# How do you avoid dependency cycle between two soft bodies?

Tags: physics, collision, soft-body

How do you setup two softbodies with collisions without getting a dependency cycle ?

A depends on B through Softbody Collision

B depends on A through Softbody Collision

Those two objects interact with each other. It’s pretty obvious that one depends on the other through collision. Why does blender consider this as a problem ?

This doesn't cause any issue when there are only two softbodies but when the scene goes more complex some objects get a simulation delay of 1 frame because of the dependancy, which is unacceptable.

Note : I can't merge the softbodies into a single mesh and use self body collision because the objects are meant to be linked to different bones

Comment: I'm interested in that as well! You should probably start a discussion on devtalk.blender.org too (if you do please let me know!) I've mentioned how this warning is odd in this bug report yesterday: https://developer.blender.org/T58050#571320

Answer (score 1):

Just add a collision simulation to both the soft body objects, and then they both collide into each other.